# recall http request from intereceptor token is not valid

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

we use token in our API , when any HTTP request we check if the token is active , if token is not active
we get new once in intereceptor

```
if (resultObj.code == AppConstants.TOKEN_IS_NOT_ACTIVE)
        getTokenOnce()
```

but how can I get that request(which can be order,report... ) and post again to the server

Comment: If the token is invalid, then the most appropriate way would be to ask the user to login again, maybe take him back to login screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you do the token authentication in your apis, so I'll just give you an example that uses a bearer token authentication type.

The signature for an okhttp interceptor is:

```kotlin
fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response
```

Inside `chain` you'll find the original request. One way this might look like is:

```kotlin
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
   val originalRequest = chain.request
   var response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)

   if (response.code == AppConstants.TOKEN_IS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
      val token = getTokenOnce()
      val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                          .header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                          .build()
      response = chain.proceed(newRequest)
   }

   return response
}
```

So the idea here is to create a new request from the original one - `newBuilder()` - and add a header with the new token. I assume that `getTokenOnce` can return the new token as a string. Maybe this needs to be tweaked a bit.

Lastly, you proceed with the request again.

One thing to bear in mind is that while setting up the interceptors, it needs to be set as an application interceptor and **not** as a network interceptor. Network interceptors don't let you proceed more than once.

Comment: see this plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443959/how-to-stop-recall-onresponse-retrofit-from-interceptor

Comment: I've just added a comment there. The callback cannot be called before the interceptors are finished. You must have another error. Maybe the new request failed as well.

Comment: if the  getTokenOnce() is http request and has a callback like any retrofit service (get) , how do I keep the code wait until new token is return