# why onResponse is called with the first response?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

When the user buys something, the order is being sent to the server.
Then, if the token is not valid, I get the new one from server and retry order with the new token that make 3 HTTP hits:

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
   val originalRequest = chain.request
   var response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)

   if (response.code == AppConstants.TOKEN_IS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
      val token = getTokenOnce() 
      val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                          .header("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                          .build()
      response = chain.proceed(newRequest)
   }

   return response
}

posConfigCall.enqueue(object : Callback<Order> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Order>, t: Throwable) {
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Order>, response: Response<Order>) {
                    try {
                        OrderCall(context).onReceiveCallOrder(response.body()) //this line

                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
```

Everything is ok, and I got the success result in the log in the third request, but the response in the callback is called with the failed and first order?

Comment: This cannot be the case. You must have had another issue somewhere. Perhaps the new request is failing too.

Comment: @Fred I am sure the new request is success (I can see the result from the server with shopping list ) but I do not know why onResponse is called with the first failed one)

Comment: @Fred could you check the question again

Comment: The way interceptors work would not allow for this. The callbacks are called only after they are intercepted. I don't know how you can see the callback being invoked with the first request. I'd advise checking logs for an error and double-check the code to see where the http calls are happening. There must be something else happening here.

Comment: @Fred Do you have fiverr

Comment: @Fred I end with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463506/retrofit-retry-with-the-new-token-request

Comment: @Fred the callback is called after    return response